# Newlines in string not writing out to file

Tags: java, string, unicode, file-io

I'm trying to write a program that manipulates unicode strings read in from a file.  I thought of two approaches - one where I read the whole file containing newlines in, perform a couple regex substitutions, and write it back out to another file; the other where I read in the file line by line and match individual lines and substitute on them and write them out.  I haven't been able to test the first approach because the newlines in the string are not written as newlines to the file.  Here is some example code to illustrate:

```
String output = "Hello\nthere!";
BufferedWriter oFile = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(
    new FileOutputStream("test.txt"), "UTF-16"));

System.out.println(output);
oFile.write(output);
oFile.close();
```

The print statement outputs

> Hello
>   there!

but the file contents are

> Hellothere!

Why aren't my newlines being written to file?

Comment: Notepad cannot properly display text files with just \n.

Comment: See if it still does it with \r\n

Comment: Yeah, I just tried that and it works.  It's strange, for some reason I remember Notepad at least displaying a not a character glyph if it just saw an 0x0A by itself, but I guess not.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should try using

```
System.getProperty("line.separator")
```

Here is an untested example

```
String output = String.format("Hello%sthere!",System.getProperty("line.separator"));
BufferedWriter oFile = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(
    new FileOutputStream("test.txt"), "UTF-16"));

System.out.println(output);
oFile.write(output);
oFile.close();
```

> I haven't been able to test the first
>   approach because the newlines in the
>   string are not written as newlines to
>   the file

Are you sure about that? Could you post some code that shows that specific fact?

Comment: Well part of it is that I only know how to read a file in one line at a time, so the newlines I was providing *were* getting written out, but only as LF, not CRLF, and weren't displaying correctly in Notepad, as kd304 pointed out.

Answer (score 1):

Use System.getProperty("line.separator") to get the platform specific newline.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using PrintWriters to get the println method known from e.g. System.out