# Newlines in string not passing out to file

Tags: java, android, string, newline, fileoutputstream

i saw similar issie

[Newlines in string not writing out to file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1133131/newlines-in-string-not-writing-out-to-file)

but it didnt helped me , this is my code

```
 try { 
           String StringBudy =String.format(mailBuddy,System.getProperty("line.separator")); 

            FileOutputStream fOut = openFileOutput("My_Sms.txt",
                                                    MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
            OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(fOut); 

            osw.write(StringBudy);
            osw.flush();
            osw.close();
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            ioe.printStackTrace();
    }
```

any ideas why Newlines in string not writing out to file ?

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: i dont have error , the My_Sms.txt file is one big line insted alot of small lines as the "mailBuddy" contains

Comment: And what if you change the osw.write(StringBudy); with ows.write(StringBudy + System.getProperty("line.separator")); ?

Comment: didnt changed the output file...still one long row

Comment: @JesusDimrix I had a similar problem, but I was using `'\n'` and BufferedWriter. I found, that to have actual line separators show, I had to use newLine(). The newLine() method just writes this: `lineSeparator = java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(new sun.security.action.GetPropertyAction("line.separator"));` [Source](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/io/BufferedWriter.java#BufferedWriter.0lineSeparator)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When creating the string insted of using \n for new line use \r\n as required by windows .

Answer (score 0):

`String.format()` will only replace the first `%s` with a newline character.

For example:

```
String.format("this%sis%sa%stest", System.getProperty("line.separator"))
```

will yield

```
this
isatest
```

One solution would be to replace all occurances of `%s` with a newline:

```
String str = mailBuddy.replace("%s", System.getProperty("line.separator"));
```

Comment: i wrote 

String StringBudy = mailBuddy.replace("%s", System.getProperty("line.separator"));

and the output of the file is the same . still one long line .

Comment: @JesusDimrix What is the value of `mailBuddy`?

Comment: a lot of sms . i send "mailBuddy" as mail and the file i created as an attachment to the same mail . the budy of the mail i shown perfectly and the file i created isnt .

Comment: if u can just give me working code of creating text file and putting string with rows in it .

Comment: @JesusDimrix -_- You'll need some way of determining where the newlines should be inserted into the string.  For example, by performing a find-and-replace on the string.